Using the Confluent BigQuery sink Kafka connector, why are my messages/records not being written to new BQ tables, but existing tables are?
I am running Kafka Connect locally using Docker, but also in AWS MSK. Both are producing the same results.
My connector configuration is as follows:
{
"name": "connector-name",
"config": {
  "connector.class": "com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.BigQuerySinkConnector",
  "allowNewBigQueryFields": "true",
  "allowBigQueryRequiredFieldRelaxation": "true",
  "autoCreateTables": "true",
  "tasks.max": "2",
  "topics": "existing-topic-name, new-topic-name",
  "project": "gcp-project-name",
  "defaultDataset": "dataset_name",
  "keyfile": "/etc/kafka/secrets/gcp-cred.key",
  "schemaRetriever": "com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.retrieve.IdentitySchemaRetriever",
  "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
  "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
  "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "<my schema registry URL goes here>",
  "value.converter.enhanced.avro.schema.support": "true",
  "schema.registry.url": "<my schema registry URL goes here>",
  "offsets.retention.minutes": 2880,
  "auto.offset.reset": "earliest",
  "enable.auto.commit": "true",
  "isolation.level": "read_committed"
}
}

A while ago (like 6-12 months ago), I started this connector only with one topic, existing-topic-name. Back then, the connector was able to create the new table on its own, and I did NOT have the following properties in my connector at all:
"allowNewBigQueryFields": "true",
  "allowBigQueryRequiredFieldRelaxation": "true",

I only had
"autoCreateTables": "true",

well when we tried adding a new topic, new-topic-name, the new table is not auto created, and new records do not enter BigQuery. I have played around with all of
"allowNewBigQueryFields": "true",
  "allowBigQueryRequiredFieldRelaxation": "true",
  "autoCreateTables": "true",
  "allowSchemaUnionization": "true",

but no combination has worked. With the original config pasted initially in my question, I don't get any errors, but I get this:
[2024-07-19 23:19:58,500] INFO [connector-name-here|task-0] [Consumer clientId=connector-consumer-connector-name-here-0, groupId=group id here] Setting offset for partition topic-names-here-0 to the committed offset FetchPosition{offset=14013, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[cluster-url-here:9098 (id: 1 rack: use1-az6)], epoch=36}} (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator:820)

or something like "found no committed offset", and occasionally an error like
Caused by: com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryException: Error getting access token for service account: connect timed out

But the table which was created 6-12 months ago by the connector originally is successfully loading in new records.
What I suspect is that the config is not correctly set up to handle the new topic. Old topic records are going in fine, but the new ones are simply "thrown out" because the connector cannot properly handle them, based on the configuration. Instead of throwing an ERROR, it simply throws out these records.
I know I don't have specific, exact error codes for each combination of config properties that I tried, but no matter what, records from new-topic-name simply do not end up in BigQuery, no matter what I try. Lastly, I know 100% that there are records in this new topic, verified by a command line consumer from another team.

hi there, can you please try changing the parameter "auto.offset.reset": "latest" - you mentioned in your question that "new" records are not getting loading so technically thinking making the value to "latest" will ensure "latest: automatically reset the offset to the latest offset" based on the documentation https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs_auto.offset.reset

Nice work there :-)
